# Has this metric been considered anywhere?

Tags: dynamical-systems, topological-dynamics

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and denote by $d$ the metric on $X$. I wondered whether the following metric $d_\infty : C(X,X)\times C(X,X) \rightarrow \mathbb{R_0^+}$ given by
$$d_\infty (f,g)= \sup_{x\in X,k\in\mathbb{N}}d(f^k(x),g^k(x))$$
has been considered and if it has a name in the literature. Thanks

Comment: This sup can be $+\infty.$

Comment: How do you know this is a metric? It seems like it might sometimes be $\infty.$  If the metric is bounded on $X,$ then it is at least always a real number.

Comment: Specific example: $X=\mathbb R$ with the standard metric, $f(x)=x+1, g(x)=x,$ then $d_\infty(f,g)=+\infty.$ So $d_\infty$ is not a metric.

Comment: If $(X,d)$ is bounded, then you can define this metric. If you consider $C(X,X)$ with the metric $d_1(f,g)=\sup_x(f(x),g(x))$ $d_1$ is also a bounded metric, then define $Y= C(X,X)^{\mathbb N}$ with the metric $d_2$ defined as $d_2((f_i),(g_i))=\sup_i d_1(f_i,g_i),$ then this is that metric on a particular subspace of $Y$ of sequences $(f,f\circ f,\dots).$ Not sure if that help.

Comment: You can also define this metric if $d$ is unbounded on a subspace  of functions $f$such that $\sup_{n,x} d(f^n(x),x)<+\infty.$

Comment: I guess $f^k$ is composition $f \circ f \circ \cdots\circ f$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews if it’s said that it’s a metric, we should assume that the sup is always finite, I think.

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte That's not how mathematical writing works. You state you conditions, prove it gives a metric. Anything else is a failure of communication, and you are the person asking other for free help. Help people help you

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I mean, the question could have been clearer, but if you write that the range of a function is $\mathbb{R}_0^+$, the reader can assume that it takes finite values.

Comment: You didn't write that. You defined something and said it was a metric, which requires proof based on the assumptions given. That's how writing works. You didn't say "If $d_infty$ is a metric, ..."

Comment: I just forgot the compactness assumption. Added.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456216/has-this-metric-been-considered-anywhere